# Dynamic Loop outputs the same on each iteration

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop

I am attempting to write a script to automate some data collection.  Initially the script runs a series of commands which are carried out by the system.  The output of these commands is stored in two text files.  Following data collection, I am attempting to implement a for loop so that a third output file is generated which lists the value of interest from the first line of output 1 and the second line of output one, as well as the relative error.  The following code completes the correct number of times, but returns the same values on all four lines.  I suspect this has to do with the filehandler variable, but am unsure how to solve the issue.

```
 for($ln = 1; $ln<5;$ln++){

    open($fh, '<',"theoretical.dat",<$ln>)
         or die "Could not open file 'theoretical.dat' $!";
    @line = split(' ',<$fh>);
    $v = $line[3];

    open($fh2, '<',"actual.dat",<$ln>)
         or die "Could not open file 'actual.dat' $!";
    @line = split(' ',<$fh2>);
    $v0 = $line[3];

    $e = abs(($v0-$v)/$v0);

   $rms = $rms + $e^2;

    my @result = ($v, $v0, $e);

    print  "@result \n";
                         }
```

The output file code has been omitted.  It contains an if/else depending upon if output should be piped into results.dat or appended.

Note that the data in question is stored in as 4 numbers per line, only the fourth of which I wish to access with this script.  From the output generated it seems that $ln is changing accordingly after each iteration, but the line being read is not despite the argument within the open command which dictates to read line number $ln.

I have tried undefing $fh and $fh2 after each loop, but it still outputs the same.

Comment: Where did you come up with that fourth argument to `open`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the line number of a file on the `open` call. In fact reopening a file will cause it to be read again starting from the top.

Without seeing your data files I can't be sure, but I think you want something like this.

Note that you can `use autodie` instead of coding an explicit test for an `open` succeeding. You must also `use strict` and `use warnings` a the top of every Perl program, and declare all of your variables using `my` as close as possible to their first point of use. I have declared `$rms` outside the loop here so that it can accumulate an aggregate sum of squares instead of being destroyed and recreated each time around the loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $theo_fh, '<', 'theoretical.dat';
open my $act_fh,  '<', 'actual.dat';

my $rms;

for my $ln (1 .. 5) {

  my $v_theo = (split ' ', <$theo_fh>)[3];
  my $v_act  = (split ' ', <$act_fh>)[3];

  my $e   = abs(($v_act - $v_theo) / $v_act);
  my $rms = $rms + $e ^ 2;

  my @result = ($v_theo, $v_act, $e);
  print "@result\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works, unfortunately with some strict errors/warnings.  It seems strange to me that I cannot specify the line of a file on the open call.  I initially wrote the script without a loop, but that requires much more time spent writing the script as certain things change upon each iteration; in that circumstance I specified the line on each open call and it worked correctly.

Comment: The standard way to access a text file is line by line. Each time you call `readline` (or `<>`) you get the next line from the file. The call to `open` will ignore any parameter after the file name, and I can't imagine where you got the idea you could put `<$line_number>` in there. I can only imagine that your `open` calls after the first were failing silently, as that would reset the read point to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Honestly I probably saw it used for a different protocol and just said "that should work".  This is the first script I've attempted to code in perl, my current instructor requested I use it but I have no experience.  That said I have minimal experience elsewhere, but that's not really the point.

Comment: I've found `perldoc` to be indispensable, but sometimes unmentioned in introductory guides.  E.g., `perldoc -f open` or `perldoc perlre`.